# Spring JPQL cannot compare java LocalDateTime - returns empty list

Tags: spring, java-8, jpql, localdatetime

I got here some piece of code of JPQL. This query returns empty list.
Any idea why it doesn't work?
In database I got stuff that matches/fullfills query.

```java
@Query("select rB from RoomBookingEntity rB where ?1  between rB.dateStart and rB.dateEnd and ?2  between rB.dateStart and rB.dateEnd") 
List<RoomBookingEntity> getAllBookingsWithIn(@Param("dateStartParam") LocalDateTime dateStartParam, @Param("dateEndParam") LocalDateTime dateEndParam);
```

Link to file:

https://github.com/.../repository/RoomBookingRepository.java

Link to repo:

https://github.com/WojciechWeg/booking_service

Comment: can you try writing the Repository method for this?

Comment: Fixed, query had mistake in it.It should be:

`@Query("select rB from RoomBookingEntity rB where rB.dateStart >= ?1 and rB.dateEnd <= ?2")`